# How to copy formatted text from a Word document into VS Code as HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, clipboard, rtf

I'm copying text from a Word document into an HTML file, but I couldn't find a way to preserve the text formatting (bold, italic, etc.).

For now the only way I found to do this was to use any online RTF editor, pasting the Word text and copying the HTML result using inspect element, but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way.

Example:

Clipboard:

> *Hello* **world**

Pasted HTML:

```
    <i>Hello</i> <b>World</b>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to paste text with links and formatting into VS Code like Obsidian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968285/how-to-paste-text-with-links-and-formatting-into-vs-code-like-obsidian)