# How to paste text with links and formatting into VS Code like Obsidian?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Text copied in Chrome]

If I copy the above text from Chrome and paste it into [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md), I get

```
People who code: we want your input. [Take the Survey](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2021)

[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask# "dismiss")
```

[image: Obsidian Screenshot]

But when I paste into VS Code or any other editor, I get

```
People who code: we want your input. Take the Survey
```

[image: VS Code Screenshot]

Video Reference: https://dsc.cloud/J/67968285.mov

How does Obsidian do it? How can I achieve the same in VS Code?

Answer (score 5):

— — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —

### The Short Answer:

> "        The VSCode editor does not support the feature you described, and VSCode will almost certainly never support any functionality that comes close to it. This is because of what VSCode is, and what VSCode does, which I will explain in detail below."

---

### The Long Answer:

So VS-Code is a text-based editor, and its purpose is to be an environment that programmers can write their code in, therefore, people using VSCode are going to preform a long list of tasks which includes, but is not limited to:
interpret, compile, execute, debug, serve, share, save, write, read, document, and run code. Now here is the problem with adding the ability to paste arbitrary data types into VSCode. Having any type of data, other than standard text in a file that you plan on using to do one of the following (this is the very short list)...

- compile,
- execute,
- debug,
- interpret
- parse,
- serve,

...will cause a syntax error to be thrown.

When you can copy, and paste, text-formatting from an external source (like a webpage), there is an extremely high probability that some unwanted formatting data will get pasted into some program you've written, and the text's format-data will end up not rendering for what ever reason (theirs a million and 87 reasons why that would happen), and you end up getting syntax errors that you can't see, so you now have no idea where the error is, despite the error message saying line number 734 column 24. In a situation like this you will have an error message that makes no sense, and you will have to start deleting things to find the issue. all because it has text-formatting data intertwined with standard text-data, which you can't see. I hope I drew a clear enough picture for you.

###### Their are other tools called word processors that implement this feature. I constantly couple G-Docs with VSCode.

---

#### Crazy Enough, not all is lost

VSCode allows extensions to make [custom editors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors). The Extension API used to create an editor (can be seen by clicking the link) lets developers build the UI using standard HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. This is enough for someone to write a Word Processor for VSCode, which surprisingly no one has done yet. When someone does create one, which I am almost certain that someone will eventually, in could support the feature your asking for.

For the record, the feature your describing is typically a word processor thing. VSCode allows you to install extensions such as [**PASTE**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=d3v.pastespecial), which copies and pastes other data types, however; when it is pasted into the editor, instead of rendering the data types like HTML, it just writes it in its text format. In other words, you might think your copying the page at first, but you will be disappointed once you paste to VSCode. I want to point out that Paste uses the [GTK-3 Clipboards API](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html), which means that if Paste were to be implemented in a word-processor, like word, or Google docs, those word processors would render the data the the Paste extension pasted into the word processor. In other words, it isn't the extension that is failing to render the Data (which as stated, can be done with the Paste Extension), but its VSCode that wonder render that data as HTML, but only accepts it as a standard text data type.

---

@W3Dojo

Answer (score 2):

What you've copied can be considered "rich text", but VSCode treats everything in your clipboard as plain text.
So it's the same as pasting via "Ctrl+Shift+V" in other programs like Word or Google Docs. It will remove any formatting, links, color, font, bold/italic, etc.

Obsidian was built with formatting in mind - it closely follows the markdown specification, so it's natural that it will try to convert any rich text to markdown.

I'm not aware of a built-in VSCode setting that will allow you to paste rich text, but I've found 2 extensions that might do the trick:

[Paste Special](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=d3v.pastespecial)
[Markdown Paste](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=telesoho.vscode-markdown-paste-image)

Comment: Tried both the extensions and they don’t seem to work in macOS.

Comment: Paste Special is the answer. I tried it on Windows, it works. You either `Ctrl + Alt + V` (not Shift), or use `Ctrl + Shift + P -> Paste Special`, and it's currently giving me an HTML paste option. I will say, you may likely want to do regex filtration of the result, as in my case the HTML is quite verbose...